# how to loop through an array and put values in unique labels in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, angularjs

### Issue

---

I am trying to display to the user the next 4 events they have got. So far I have used `splice` on the array to select the first 4 `objects`. So now I have these objects I need to be able to loop through the array and display the correct data.

All the labels are unique and will have different names.

I don't know if the way i am doing this is the correct way. This is a learning project for me.

### Code

---

My ASP.NET code for the 4 events looks like this:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 25px; border-left: 4px solid #21cd25; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: #21cd25; padding-right: 10px;"></span>
        <span style="font-weight: 500;">10 Days - </span>
        <span>Holiday</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 5px; border-left: 4px solid #f6bb42; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" style="color: #f6bb42; padding-right: 10px;"></span>
        <span style="font-weight: 500;">3 Weeks - </span>
        <span>Paternity</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 5px; border-left: 4px solid #cd2121; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: #cd2121; padding-right: 10px;"></span>
        <span style="font-weight: 500;">1 Week - </span>
        <span>Holiday</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 5px; border-left: 4px solid #21cd25; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: #21cd25; padding-right: 10px;"></span>
        <span style="font-weight: 500;">1 Day - </span>
        <span>Bank Holiday</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the first row says the next event is *10 Days -* away and below that you can see it is a *Holiday*. If you keep looking through there are 4 different labels for this information.

Controller code:

```
function GetNext4UserEvents() {

    var top4 = _allUserEvents.splice(0, 4);

}
```

I have not really added much to this as i just can't think of the best way to do it. As you can see though i am getting the top 4 objects.

The object looks like this:

```
0: Object
    color: "#cc0000"
    end: "2016-02-20"
    id: 6
    start: "2016-02-10"
    title: "Test2"
```

Comment: It's probably just me, but I'm totally lost on what it is you're trying to accomplish. Where is the Angular part in all of this?

Comment: @Lex I thought (Don't quote me new to angular) that i would in someway be able to use `ng-repeat` to display the values in the array to the asp code.

Comment: Angular is useful if you need to dynamically update the UI (ie update the UI without refreshing the entire page). If this data isn't going to change, it looks like your ASP code is already accomplishing what you need? I would recommend reading thru an Angular tutorial.

Comment: @ben-clarke Absolutely you can do that, what I'm not understanding is where in your markup you're wanting to display the values from your array. Or are you wanting to generate the markup that you've shown using Angular?

Comment: @Lex Where the values say `10 Days -` and `3 Weeks -` etc i want the `start` from my object to be displayed. Where the values say `Holiday` and `Paternity` etc i want `title` to be displayed from my object.

Comment: @CalvinBelden This data is 100% going to change. The information there now is fake. The data will change depending on the user logged in etc.

Comment: Right, but is the data going to change while the user is on the page? Or is this data known when you're building the HTML on the server (ie in your asp template)?

Comment: @CalvinBelden Yes, if the user adds an event while on the page that is in the top 4 it should update.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I haven't completely misunderstood your question, but here's a stab at outputting your events. Maybe it's not exactly what you were after, but hopefully it can serve as a starting point. I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x3ouke5/) where you can mess around with the code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 25px; border-left: 4px solid #21cd25; font-size: 12px;" ng-repeat="event in sampleEvents">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="glyphicon {{event.color | findIcon}}" ng-style="{'color': event.color, 'padding-right': '10px'}"></span>
        <span style="font-weight: 500;">{{event.start | daysOut}} - </span>
        <span>{{event.title}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", ["angularMoment"])
  .filter("daysOut", function(moment) {
    return function(input) {
      return moment.duration(moment(input) - moment()).humanize();
    };
  })
  .filter("findIcon", function() {
    return function(input) {
      switch (input) {
        case "#cc0000":
          return "glyphicon-remove";
          break;
        case "#008000":
          return "glyphicon-ok";
          break;
        case "#ffa500":
          return "glyphicon-question-sign";
          break;
      }
      return "glyphicon-ok";
    }
  })
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.sampleEvents = [{
      color: "#cc0000",
      end: "2016-04-01",
      id: 1,
      start: "2016-03-19",
      title: "Event 1"
    }, {
      color: "#008000",
      end: "2016-04-03",
      id: 2,
      start: "2016-03-22",
      title: "Event 2"
    }, {
      color: "#ffa500",
      end: "2016-04-15",
      id: 3,
      start: "2016-04-02",
      title: "Event 3"
    }, {
      color: "#008000",
      end: "2016-04-14",
      id: 4,
      start: "2016-03-13",
      title: "Event 4"
    } ];
  });
```